# If we implement cache coherence why do we need locks?

Tags: caching

Does cache coherence state we serial writes thus any write in the critical part be update by only one core at a time . As if we use MESI , a block can be written by a core only when in M state so when the core sends a BusRdx and write no other caches have the block , so if any other block wants to write to it means it would get the most update value which would mean a serial execution so why are lock needs

But when i use

```
sum = 0
     pragma op parallel
     for(i=0;i<1000000;i++)
     sum = sum + 1
```

The sum value is never equal to 1000000

why is that shouldnt cache coherence when another core tries to write to it , it recieve the most updated value

Theory problem, i beleive we should not need locks for this

Comment: There are a separate load and store here, MESI by itself does not prevent another processor from taking ownership of the cache line (and write to it) *between* the load and store. See also: [Is incrementing an int effectively atomic in specific cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396999/555045)